# Typescript. What to do if module doesn't have @types?

Tags: typescript

I'm developing react application using typescript.

Here is my `App.tsx`. As you can see `react` has `@types` but other modules don't

[image]

Is there any way to stub these modules or use them as `any` or another

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/index.d.ts https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts

Comment: You can also search for `@types` over here: http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Answer (score 14):

All the modules you're referring have `@types`. But let's assume that the module you're using doesn't, e.g. the library kea([keajs](https://github.com/keajs/kea)) doesn't have `@type` defined to this date.

The simplest way to solve this is to create a declaration file `declarations.d.ts` and declare the problematic module like this:

```
declare module "kea"
```

Then in your `tsconfig.json` you need to be sure that in `include` property you have something like:

```
...
"include": [
  "src", "declarations.d.ts"
]
...
```

Or just put `declarations.d.ts` inside your `src` folder so you don't need to touch this file.

Be wary that you won’t have any types for the module (the module will be just a big `any`); but you won’t have any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still wondering what to do in case of missing `@types/module` type definitions, [dts-gen](https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen) can cover the missing type and generate a `.d.ts` for that specific module.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I am pretty sure these modules have `@types`. Check here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-redux
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-persist
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router

If you use NPM, you can install, react-redux for instance, doing:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-redux
```

Comment: So what if i'm using modules that don't have types?

Comment: @Herrgott Then you can write a `.d.ts` file containing some declarations. These declarations can be as easy as `any` or as complex as you need.

Comment: I should write '`any`' declarations manually for each package? It looks uncomfortably if i just need a stub for package

Comment: It seems to me that i just spent my time with typescript

Comment: @Herrgott actually, almost every used package has its own definition. And writing a fake definition should not take more than one line. IMHO, giving up TypeScript just for that is a dramatic error.

Comment: is there universal code for every fake `.d.ts` module?

Comment: No, but you can include every unknown source using `require` with one single line.