# I can't use createRoot function in react-dom/client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
// This opts into the new behavior!
ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

If this code is executed, the error happens like following.

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-dom/client'. 'E:/Workspace/React/welcomedev-react-starter/node_modules/react-dom/client.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-dom` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-dom/client';`
1 | import React from 'react';

> 2 | import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
> |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 3 | import App from './App';
> 4 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

I want the answer.

Comment: Well, did you try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-dom`?

Answer (score 14):

Be sure you have the correct types versions installed. Try running:

`npm install --save-dev @types/react@18 @types/react-dom@18`

Don't rely on your IDE to pick up everything correctly. In my case I had to manually type the import and use `createRoot` like this:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);   // notice the '!'
root.render(<App />);
```

Notice how you need to tell typescript that you are sure your root won't be null with the exclamation mark ('!'). See more info in ['Updates to Client Rendering APIs'](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for my mental health :)

Comment: if I am using the same call but with .js file with ts checking is enabled "using tsconfig" is there a way to solve this error ?

Comment: @yaminoyuki I'm not sure what you mean, because this is relevant to a typescript issue, you shouldn't get any error if you're using plain js files. Just make sure you delete  typescript-related things like the `!`. You also don't need to install the types.
If I didn't get what you mean feel free to create a new question and tag/message me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this example from https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

Have you tried `createRoot(container!)` ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: const container = document.getElementById('app') as Element;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript with react, then you need to import relative dependencies that support types and meets other typescript condition.
So try running the command `npm i --save-dev @types/react-dom`

And in case you are working with dependencies that doesn't support typescript then you can get around with this method. Hope this helps.

[Typescript. What to do if module doesn't have @types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388560/typescript-what-to-do-if-module-doesnt-have-types)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ReactDOM` before `createRoot()` does solve this issue.
Example-

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement)
```