# How to solve "Uncaught TypeError: ReactDOM.createRoot is not a function"?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm using Vite with React. Just downgraded react version to 18 to 16 but my app is broken. Do I have to downgrade vite version too or how can I use react with vite ?

Error:

`main.jsx:6 Uncaught TypeError: ReactDOM.createRoot is not a function at main.jsx:6:10`

main.jx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './main.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "jetrients",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-qr-barcode-scanner": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: See this may it will help you               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71836313/i-cant-use-createroot-function-in-react-dom-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

with

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Also be sure that `react` and `react-dom` are the same version

Comment: now I get main.jsx:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: StrictMode is not defined
    at

Comment: you either have to import it from react or just use `React.StrictMode`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);  
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that the versions of **react** and **reactDOM** are the same and replace this code

[image]